# Running PowerShell in SIF using the Command Task

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to build out some simple PowerShell tasks into SIF tasks, and I am really hitting a wall with the simplest stuff. My estimation is that a Command task is for exe and console apps and not PowerShell commands. Example below.

My JSON configuration file dsc.json

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "InstallPath": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "DefaultValue": "Start-DscConfiguration",
            "Description": "DSC Install Path."
        }
    },
    "Tasks": {
        "Test-Get-Children": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "Get-ChildItem",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-Path",
                    "*.log"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Test-DSC": {
            "Type": "Command",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "Start-DscConfiguration",
                "Arguments": [
                    "-Path",
                    ".//Sitecore",
                    "-Wait",
                    "-Verbose"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Parameters PS1 file.

```
$configsRoot            = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot Configs

$sitecoreDSC = @{
    Path                = Join-Path $configsRoot dsc.json
}

echo $sitecoreDSC
```

My install PS1 file

```
. $PSScriptRoot\parameters.ps1

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreDSC
```

On the Get-Children command my error is this. It seems like it is trying to run the arg on its on command:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\gh\ScriptTest\PrepServer-Path' because it does not exist.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31 char:13
>   +             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\gh\ScriptTest\PrepServer-Path:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

On the Start-DscConfiguration my error is this. This is because `Start-DscConfiguration` was executed with specifying the path. Again, the args were ignored.

> Invoke-CommandTask : Cannot convert 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
>   +                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
>   +                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. Try running `Get-Help Invoke-CommandTask` to see the documentation and guidance on the built in command task.

You can import arbitrary powershell functions by registering them in a custom module.

1. Create a psm1 file
2. In the psm1, use `Register-SitecoreInstallExtension` to register the function as a task
3. Add the psm1 in the modules section of your config

This will enable you to register existing or custom functions into the scope of your install.

E.g. `Register-SitecoreInstallExtension -Command Start-DSConfiguration -As StartDSC -Type Task`

Will enable you to use the task type `StartDSC` in your config.

In SIF V2, this will be even easier as a new feature simplifies custom function registration.

If you really need or want to put raw powershell in your config, check out [SIX](https://github.com/SoftServeInc/SitecoreInstallExtensions/blob/master/SitecoreInstallExtensions/Tasks/Invoke-ScriptBlockTask.ps1)

Comment: The configuration guide available at: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework/1x/Sitecore_Installation_Framework_12.aspx should explain things further

Comment: I started to do this in a repo of SIX and switched to tasks thinking it would be more consistent. Maybe I will just go back to that route. Thanks.

Comment: Tasks will be simpler and easier to share as raw PowerShell in configs will be more difficult to modify. Registration is really simple. Please also check the examples here (notably 6.modules.json and the extensions.psm1) https://github.com/Kieranties/SIfSug/tree/master/Examples